# Python: Can a dictionary have both tuples and strings as key ?

Tags: python-2.7

Can I have a single dictionary, in which some of the keys are tuples and other are strings, at the same time ?

Comment: dictionary keys are not typed. As long as they're hashable it's OK. So, the answer is yes (try it instead of asking a question, you'll see).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only two requirements for dictionary keys in python is that they must be unique (ie - you can't use the same key twice in a single dictionary) and each key must be hashable (ie - it must have a unique id for comparison). Ints, floats, strings, dictionaries, tuples, .. etc are all hashable.

Example of using a tuple and a string as keys:

```
>>> mydict = {('you', 'can'):'do', 'this':('if', 'you', 'want')}
>>> print(mydict)
{'this': ('if', 'you', 'want'), ('you', 'can'): 'do'}
>>> mydict[('you', 'can')]
'do'
>>> mydict['this']
('if', 'you', 'want')
```

Example showing tuples and strings have a hash method :

```
>>> ('you', 'can').__hash__()
-5095345937749811518
>>> 'this'.__hash__()
2314053222244391272
```